Ubuntu 24.04 gnome-remote-desktop
So I'm not a IT person. I'm attempting to find a way that using gnome-remote-desktop to be able to log in from windows rdp client and reconnect where i left off without looking like a brand new login. This is the way that windows to windows seems to work and I want to emlute that behavior .
I'm using gnome 46 and ubuntu 24.04 on wayland.
Thank you for the assistance
